# How to create dynamic id in elastic search client in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am trying to post data elk server using elastic search client.I need to pass dynamic id.Below the code I am using

```
require 'elasticsearch'

module PostDataToElasticsearchConcern
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
   included do
      helper_method :post_executions_to_elasticsearch
    end
  
    def post_executions_to_elasticsearch(username,mac_address,parametername)

        json = {
          "mac_address"  => mac_address.to_s,
          "parameter_name" => parametername.to_s,
          "user_name"  => username.to_s,
          "time"  => Time.now.utc.iso8601
        }
       postdata=json.to_s.gsub!("=>",":")
       puts "JSON----------------------------"+postdata.to_s
      
        client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url:"My Server:9200"
       response = client.index(index: 'testingapp', body: json, id: '1')

      end
  end
```

Now I have passed id as 1. But id needs to be created dynamically.how to create dynamic id?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create dynamic id with below code.

```
  response = client.index(index: 'testingapp', body: json)
```

Removing **id** will created dynamic id.